# Shopping bill recognition application OpenCV:Exctact only the bill from the image

Tags: opencv, feature-extraction

i have to write a openCV application to extract certain part from an image (shopping bill). Im not sure which filters or functions i should use to accomplish this (i.e removing the background noise such as hands).Can some one give me some hint on which functions and filters will work best to remove such background noise and to extract the shopping bill part from the image.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subjective question, for it is **highly** dependent on how your image is taken.

Knowing, and controlling if possible, things like the color of the bill, its geometry, the possible colors of the background, range of distance between the bill and the camera, lighting, etc, are of uttermost importance here and will ultimately define the best approach, so I can't give you an objective answer to your question.

I can however try to point you to the right direction, so I suggest you should take a look at the [OpenCV tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc/table_of_content_imgproc.html#table-of-content-imgproc), in special [segmentation algorithms](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html), [hough transforms](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) and [generic object detectors](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier).

Answer (score 0):

general noise reduction: gaussian or median blurring will help you to achieve a low pass filtering operation.

**fact 1:** shopping bills are black and white

approach: use [color detection](http://colorizer.org/). Taking the HLS equivalent of your image -using cvtColor- and looking at the lightness channel will help you.

**fact 2:** shopping bills have plain white background

approach: using binary threshold with an addition of contour finding algorithm -using findContours- could help you to extract the bill region.

**fact 3:** shopping bills have numbers

approach: You can add OCR to filter out regions not having any numbers inside. Hard to implement, though.

**fact 4:** shopping bills are quadliteral

approach: shape detection is not hard to implement. I assume there are so many works on that. I once recognized squares succesfully with "hu moment comparison" method. If you have a rectangular shot of bill, there could be open source implementations, search for "detect largest rectangle opencv". If you are having shots from different angles, go through these papers, codes and tutorials:

http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~nmb/papers/06-PRD.pdf

http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/

https://github.com/drewnoakes/quadrilateral-finder

http://aishack.in/tutorials/an-introduction-to-contours/

http://www.scielo.org.mx/pdf/cys/v15n2/v15n2a5.pdf

basically, you need to find the "extreme points" of your blobs somehow, than decide if it is a quadliteral or not.